# Default android project in Eclipse starts empty

Tags: android, eclipse

I created a default android project with Eclipse, following [this](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/running-app.html) tutorial but it starts empty.
Project name: PreçoCerveja

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the project name.

Character " ç " was not allowed. I just changed it to " c ".

Comment: Yeah. That's the most stupid problem i've had in past days and it took me a while to figure it out. Just sharing.